# Parsing a table to a String from a link with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

like said in the title I would like to parse a table into a string or string array so, clean text, from the website of a local bus operator. The website has a table that appears in the middle of the page with the time of the buses in the following hour for that stop.

I haven't used Jsoup for a while but I can't for the life of me figure out why what I have isn't working. I tried two suggestions from answers I found here to similar questions but neither worked and I am afraid that the Elements I have with the table is actually empty as it never returns anything...

The website from where I'm extracting the data is the following: http://www.stcp.pt/pt/viajar/horarios/?paragem=AAL2&t=smsbus
(If this doesn't show any table then it's because this stop is nighttime only, so please try this one for example: http://www.stcp.pt/pt/viajar/horarios/?paragem=HB1&t=smsbus which should work in daytime)

My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class STCPreaderMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String ParagemID = "AAL2"; // HB1, AAL2 for night

        String getUrl = "http://www.stcp.pt/pt/viajar/horarios/?paragem=REPLACE&t=smsbus";

        getUrl = getUrl.replace("REPLACE", ParagemID);

        String text = "";

        System.out.println(getUrl);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(getUrl).get();

        Elements tableElements = doc.select("table#smsBusResults");

        System.out.println(tableElements.text());

        Elements tableHeaderEles = tableElements.select("thead tr th");
        System.out.println("headers");
        for (int i = 0; i < tableHeaderEles.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(tableHeaderEles.get(i).text());
        }
        System.out.println();

        Elements tableRowElements = tableElements.select(":not(thead) tr");

        for (int i = 0; i < tableRowElements.size(); i++) {
            Element row = tableRowElements.get(i);
            System.out.println("row");
            Elements rowItems = row.select("td");
            for (int j = 0; j < rowItems.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(rowItems.get(j).text());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

(Sorry if the code is badly formatted, sometimes eclipse's auto formatter acts out and I was never that good at formatting anyway :( )

Basically my problem is that I can find the  line declaring a table with name smsBusResults but when I actually go and search for it using table#smsBusResults, I appear to find nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find the table because it is not in the URL that you posted...
When you go to that URL, the browser is downloading other URLs, one of them is http://www.stcp.pt/pt/itinerarium/soapclient.php?codigo=AAL2&linha=0, which contains your table.
Open your browser's `Developer Tools` (press F12) and watch the network traffic - you will see that there are several `GET` requests, one of them contains the table.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that was possible, thanks! Then should I just extract the data from the website you posted now?

Comment: EDIT: Thanks! My code seems to work now, just replaced the link I had with the one you posted here and it worked! I knew nothing about GET requests, as I was never much into networking or websites :s

Comment: Of couse my friend, marked! (Forgot I could do that, I'm still kinda new to stackoverflow :) )